# SQL Insert Column not found - Maps

Tags: java, hashmap, sql-insert, h2db

I want to create multiple HashMaps with same keys. I fixed this by using @SQLInsert.
But now I am getting a `Column not found` Error, maybe I annotate it wrong?

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "BACKUP_INVENTORY", joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "BACKUP_ID"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "INVENTORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
@Column(name="AMOUNT")
@SQLInsert(sql="MERGE INTO BACKUP_INVENTORY(BACKUP_ID, INVENTORY_ID,  AMOUT) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")
private Map<InventoryItemIdentifier, Number> backupCount;
```

**Error -**

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feld "INVENTORY_ID" nicht gefunden
Column "INVENTORY_ID" not found; SQL statement:
MERGE INTO BACKUP_INVENTORY(BACKUP_ID, INVENTORY_ID,  AMOUT) VALUES (?, ?, ?)[42122-190]
```

Maybe some one have a better idea to create multiple HashMaps with same Keys?

**Example:**

> HashMap1 : key=abc value=5 ...
>
> HashMap2 : key=abc value=2 ...

Comment: Is the column called `AMOUT` or is a typo? If the column is called `AMOUNT` instead, that would explain the error.

Comment: Can you get your database system to print a list of the columns in the table?

Comment: Do you mean to print out all keys an the right value for it?

Comment: Well, anything that would show us that `INVENTORY_ID` actually exists in the table. Something like a `describe backup_inventory`

Comment: I hope i understand it correct. Since Inventory_Id stands for the InventoryItemIdentifier. I printed all entrys of the map out after it was created and all ids and values are correct. I am also able to create a 2. Map and also replace values of the maps but some where late at the startup the error occurs :/